# How to get Mailgun response with Laravel Mail

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun, laravel-mail

How can I get the response from Mailgun using Laravel mail.
Here is my code.

```
// In User Model.
$mail = \Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use ($parsed_template) {
          $message
            ->to('abhi@toemail.com')
            ->subject('Test')
            ->setBody($parsed_template, 'text/html')
            ->addPart('Hello, welcome to Laravel!', 'text/plain');

     });
```

I can get the response in the Listener using the Mailgun EVENT.

```
protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
        'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent' => [
            'App\Listeners\MailGunMailListner',
        ],
    ];

//   'App\Listeners\MailGunMailListner',

public function handle(MessageSent $event)
    {
        dd($event->message->getId());
    }
```

I can get the response in the Listener, but I want to know how can I access it in the User Model.

Thanks